# jquery dynamic class

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class based on a predefined variable to a specific id element using jquery. This is what I've tried so far but it's not working. Any help would be apriciated.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="test">THIS TEXT SHOULD BE RED</div>
```

This is my JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var color = "red";
  $("#test").addClass(color);
};
```

This is my CSS

```
.red {
  color:red;
}
```

[View it on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dhKgL)

Comment: You have a syntax error, last line: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`.

Comment: specifically, a missing closing `)` on the last line.  Your debugger ("what's one of those?", you say!) would have told you this.

Answer (score 2):

[It works just fine when you fix the document.ready call.](http://jsfiddle.net/wZyfP/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ..code..
}); //you forgot your closing paren here
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var color = "red";
  $("#test").addClass(color);
});​
```

You missed the `")"` at the end of the document `ready`.

Comment: "spot the difference" answers are not helpful, IMHO

Comment: written in haste. my bad